# How to copy colors of cell range to other cell range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've made a calendar in Excel for my work shifts. e.g,

C55:I55 contains the dates of a week (1-jun, 2-jun, 3-jun etc.)
C56:I56 contain shifts, which are colored based on conditional formatting (I work early/late/night shifts which have different colors)

Now, I want the date row (C55:I55) to copy the colors of the shifts row (C56:I56). I've got some basic VBA code that can do this for one cell, but how can I make it work for a row?

I've already looked on the web and StackOverflow for a solution, but I can't find the specific solution I'm looking for.

This is the code I currently have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Range("C55").Interior.Color = Range("I55").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Sub
```

-

**EDIT**

So, with some help and tweaking, I got it to work using this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Dim i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rooster 2020")

        For i = 3 To 9
           .Cells(63, i).Interior.Color = .Cells(64, i).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Now I'm just curious, is there a way to include more lines than just "63" and "64" in the above example?

Comment: If you just want to color the date same as the conditional formatting on shifts, then abandon VBA altogether. Take note that you can extend the range where your conditional formatting applies.

Comment: Hey L42, my "shift" cells are conditionally formatted based on their values. E.g. shift 1 through 10 are blue, and 11 through 20 are yellow. Are you saying it's possible to extend this conditional formatting to the "date" cells? And if so, how?

Comment: It is too long to put in here to refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57880937/2685412).

Comment: @Mogaru did my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57867628/11167163) help you ? I edited it yesterday

Comment: Hey @dorian, thanks for your reply. I've been occupied for a while so I'm sorry that I couldn't answer earlier. I still didn't get it to work somehow, even with your code. Maybe it's my Excel version? I've kinda given up now. Thanks anyway for your kind help!!!

Comment: @Mogaru you just got to copy and paste the code in « sheet » then put color in row 62 then type something in a cell of row 61 and it will take color, try it

Answer (score 2):

Conditional formatting <> `.Interior.Color` so you need to copy paste formats, like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    'This will copy the conditional formatting
    'Change the sheet name. ThisWorkbooks points to the workbook holding the code
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")
        .Range("C55").Copy
        .Range("I55").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

    'This will only copy the color from the cell
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")
        .Range("I55").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = .Range("C55").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: this code will copy only colors or all formatting such as borders, alignments etc?

Comment: Yeah, you just need to change the ranges to suit your needs.

Comment: Hey, so your code kinda copied the contents too and broke my sheet :(. I don't really know what happened. I replaced "MySheet" with the name of the sheet, and the ranges to "C61:I61" and "C62:I62"

Comment: It is totally impossible that my code copied the contents it only does paste the formats, or in the second case, the interior color displayed by the conditional formatting.

Comment: Hey, so I just tried again and I'm getting a 1004 error. I'm a coding rookie btw

Comment: Which line gets highlighted?

Comment: It doesn't highlight any line. It just gives the 1004 error code :(

Comment: When you press debug the VBA editor opens and highlights a line with yellow background.

Comment: I don't really know where the debug button is, but when I run the code line by line (F8) it crashes at "End With"

Answer (score 1):

With this code you just copy the interior color:

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim y As Long, i As Long
    Dim arrLines As Variant

    'Colored Lines
    arrLines = Array(1, 4, 23)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For y = LBound(arrLines) To UBound(arrLines)

            For i = 3 To 9
               'Color the next line from the line which has colot
               .Cells(arrLines(y) + 1, i).Interior.Color = .Cells(arrLines(y), i).Interior.Color
            Next i

        Next y
    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Hey... this is just his question and yours is using a loop because..?  `.Interior.Color` doesn't get the color from the cell if it's given by a conditional formatting. If the OP want's to copy the conditional formatting this won't help, neither will for copying the color. Test it out please.

Comment: That's better, but the loop is still unncessary, the OP is copying a given range, there is no need to loop through it.

Comment: Hey, so funny enough this code, with a bit of tweaking, is doing exactly what I want it to do. Now, is there a way to add multiple lines behind the .Cells property? I will update my code in the original post.

Comment: I've copied your code and edited the parameters, however, it's doing nothing for me anymore.

Comment: @Mogaru change ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` & `arrLines = Array(1, 4, 23)` to fulfill your needs. `arrLines` includes the colored lines

Comment: Cool, thanks, it semi works! :D It just works once, based on the values that are already entered. Whenever I change a shift, the colors dont change along. Any idea why?

Comment: the code works only for Sheet1 `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: So I just made a completely new sheet, and tried your code. Your code copies the given color to the row below, not the conditional formatted color :(

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you don't need `VBA` to do this. You can do *conditional formatting* by just extending the range where it is applied.

Consider you have a data like this:

[image]

You need to do the following steps:

1. Select `C56` and create the conditional formatting using the rule type *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*. So based on your comment, your formula should look like this: `=AND(C$56>=1,C$56<=10)` (for blue) and `=AND(C$56>=11,C$56<=20)` (for red). It is important to note though that in the formula, we lock the row (absolute reference) while the column is moving (relative reference) using `C$56` meaning it will always refer to the value at row 56 but column will adjust. So the formatting will be based on `C$56`, `D$56`, `E$56`... and `I$56` values.

   [image]
2. Now after creating the rules, you need to edit the range where it applies to.

   [image]
3. After changing the range, press apply.

   [image]

Take note that although you created the *conditional formatting* on `C56`, you applied it on `$C$55:$I$56`. After doing all those steps, you'll see the result like below.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I like your solution and I've tried it. However, whenever I copy your formula I get an error (because there is a comma in the formula) and no conditional formatting happens. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mogaru Try `;` semi-colon instead of `,` comma. I use the English version so we use `,` comma as argument separator. Other international versions of Excel uses `;` semi-colon.